# Angular 5: Extract i18n and create messages.xlf without angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, internationalization, angular-cli

I'm currently working on an angular 4.4 project that was created with but ejected from angular-cli. In our webpack.config, we use `AOTPlugin` and `ExtractI18nPlugin` from `@ngtools/webpack` to use angulars Ahead of Time compiling and extract the `messages.xlf` based on our i18n-Html-Attributes. The `messages.xlf` gets updated every time we run our build task with this webpack config.

After updating to Angular 5.2.1, we replaced `AOTPlugin` with `AngularCompilerPlugin` as described in the Readme for `@ngtools/webpack`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack. Works perfectly fine.

However, there is no mention on how to migrate from the `ExtractI18nPlugin`, which also seems to be deprecated. If we leave it in our webpack.config, the build task fails with the error message:
**Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+**. Of course, all our dependencies are up to date and have been completely reinstalled several times (including the angular-cli, which we don't use for our build task)

The new AngularCompilerPlugin has some options regarding i18n defined in the interface **AngularCompilerPluginOptions**:

```
  ...
  i18nInFile?: string;
  i18nInFormat?: string;
  i18nOutFile?: string;
  i18nOutFormat?: string;
  locale?: string;
  ...
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.ts#L57

But they (seem to) have no effect and there is no documentation on how to use them.

While looking for a solution, I found this example project demonstrating our current scenario, but it only worked until the angular 5 beta. Now there is an github issue describing our exact problem: https://github.com/ocombe/i18n-demo-no-cli

Any ideas on how to get our i18n extraction running again with angular 5.X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution: The `AngularCompilerPlugin` skips the i18n-extraction if the option `skipCodeGeneration` (which disables AOT-Compiling) is set to `true`.

Our working configuration for i18n extraction now looks like this:

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
  mainPath: 'src/main.ts',
  i18nOutFile: path.join('src', 'i18n', 'messages.xlf'),
  i18nOutFormat: 'xlf',
  locale: 'en',
  sourceMap: true,
  tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',
  skipCodeGeneration: false,
  compilerOptions: {}
})
```